# Issue with printing the value of JSON data from POST request

Tags: ios, json, swift

Essentially I have the following function that responds to POST Request and displays JSON data.

I would like to just print the results of this data by printing the value of del_tex

At the top of the ViewController I define the variable structure as:

```
var structure = [NotesStructure]()
```

NotesStructure is the structure of the JSON received:

```
import UIKit

struct NotesStructure: Codable {
    let del_tex: String

}
```

The following is the JSON function that fetches and processes the data. I try to print the value of del_tex but get the error that structure has no value `del_tex`

```
private func fetchJSON() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/example/example"),
        let value = driverName.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
        else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "person=\(driverName)&serial=\(peronNum)".data(using: .utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }


        do {
            self.structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([NotesStructure].self,from:data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                print(self.structure.del_tex)

            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }

        }.resume()

}
```

Comment: What is the format of your response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is an array so you first need to access the array, either only the first element

```
do {
     self.structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([NotesStructure].self,from:data)
     if let first = self.structure.first {
          print(first.del_tex)
     }
 ...
```

or print the whole array

```
do {
     self.structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([NotesStructure].self,from:data)
     for item in self.structure {
          print(item.del_tex)
     }
...
```